# Entity Framework Core Throwing Exception: The LINQ expression could not be translated with PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to filter a query in ASP.NET Core 3.1, using Entity Framework Core 3.1.8 with the entities bellow:

```
public class ProductVariant
{
        public Guid DepositId { get; set; }
        public Collection<ProductVariantProperty> ProductVariantProperties { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVariantProperty
{
    public int ProductAttributeId { get; set; }
    public int ProductAttributeValueId { get; set; }
}

This is the query I'm using:
    
var result = productVariantRepository
                .Where(p => p.ProductVariantProperties.Any(x => x.ProductAttributeId == 12))
                .ToList();
```

Entity Map:

```
builder.Entity<ProductVariant>(b =>
{
     b.ToTable(CommerceConsts.DbTablePrefix + "ProductVariants", CommerceConsts.DbSchema);
     b.ConfigureByConvention();
     b.Property(x => x.ProductVariantProperties).HasColumnType("jsonb");
     b.HasOne<Deposit>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.DepositId).IsRequired();
});
```

This is the exception:

> **The LINQ expression** 'DbSet
> .Where(p => p.ProductVariantProperties
> .Any(x => x.ProductAttributeId == 12))' **could not be translated**. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync().

It only works when using **productVariantRepository.AsEnumerable()**, but this returns all object from the table.

**The main go is to use Json property with jsonb, but only the query filter is not working**

https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco

Comment: Did you try                .Where(p => p.ProductVariantProperties.AsQueryable().Any(x => x.ProductAttributeId == 12))

Comment: @Chronicle, yes! Same problem. Thanks!

Comment: So you're using a json column? From your linked documentation you'll probably need to use one of the `EF.Functions.Json...` functions.

Comment: why is ProductVariantProperties marked as a collection? when its a ` b.Property(x => x.ProductVariantProperties).HasColumnType("jsonb");` that doesnt make sense does it

Answer (score 2):

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet .Where(p => p.ProductVariantProperties
> .Any(x => x.ProductAttributeId == 12))' could not be translated.

This error occurs because the table `ProductVariant` doesn't have column name `ProductVariantProperties`. You can try to open database to check again.

That's why your linq cannot be translated to SQL statement. Something like: *There is no column name `ProductVariantProperties` in the table `ProductVariant`*.

I suggest to filter `ProductVariantProperty` that including `ProductAttributeId` property. Then, assigning the value to `ProductVariantProperties` property.

Comment: the property is right, see again please:  public Collection<ProductVariantProperty> ProductVariantProperties { get; set; }

Comment: @MichelAndrade No. You have to check in your database. There is no column name `ProductVariantProperties`. You cannot create a column with `Collection` type, it's just used to mapping.

Comment: Ok, Tân, you are right! But I'm using this field only as a json property, take a look https://ibb.co/qdXZ4qk

Comment: It is saving and returning the data in the database, but it's not filtering, I'm working with this doc: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco

Comment: @MichelAndrade It's weird. But what's happen if you try `var list = productVariantRepository.ToList()`? Have you got a list? If yes, I guess you need to work with that `list` instead of just `productVariantRepository.Where(...).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

ProductVariantProperty doesn't have any field that can be used to connect this two tables. Add ProductVariantId to ProductVariantProperty and join this two tables them. After this you can select by ProductAttributeId.